# Forcing tableGrob() to fit in .tiff file

Tags: r

I am trying to output a tableGrob into a .tiff, but it is a bit long. I've tried to get the area of the table fit into the .tiff file, but it is always cut off unless I drastically change the font size to an unreadable size. Is there a way to force the tableGrob to fin into the .tiff file without any cut off?

```
table.plot <- structure(list(A = c(2.8, 0.5, 1.3, 5.7, 6.5, 1.1, 3.3, 1, 16.9, 
8.6, 6.3, 22.2, 14.8, 1.3, 7.9, 12.4, 31, 9.9, 13.2, 26.2, 2), 
    B = c(13.7, 10.6, 12.7, 20.6, 13.2, 11.2, 14.7, 11.7, 22.3, 
    12.9, 12.9, 19.5, 20.6, 11.1, 17, 20.3, 43.1, 18.2, 20.9, 
    26.7, 10.1), C = c(0.4, 0, 0.3, 1, 0.3, 0.1, 0.5, 0.2, 1.2, 
    0.3, 0.3, 0.9, 1, 0.1, 0.7, 1, 3.3, 0.8, 1.1, 1.6, 0), D = c(29.7, 
    18, 23.9, 46.2, 33.1, 20.1, 32.6, 21.1, 93.1, 39.9, 33, 116.8, 
    76.1, 21.4, 49, 66.7, 166.5, 53.7, 69.1, 127.4, 21)), row.names = c("G01", 
"G02", "G03", "G04", "G05", "G06", "G07", "G08", "G09", "G10", 
"G11", "G12", "H01", "H02", "H03", "H04", "H05", "H06", "H07", 
"H08", "Host.1"), class = "data.frame")

tt1 <- ttheme_minimal(
  core = list(fg_params = list(fontsize = 8), 
              padding = unit(c(0.1, 0.1), "mm")),
  colhead = list(bg_params = list(fill = "white"), 
                 fg_params = list(fontsize = 8, fontface = "bold")), 
  rowhead = list(fg_params = list(fontsize = 8, fontface = "bold"))
)

g <- tableGrob(table.plot, theme = tt1)


g <- gtable_add_grob(g,
                     grobs = rectGrob(gp = gpar(fill = NA, lwd = 2)),
                     t = 2, b = nrow(g), l = 1, r = ncol(g))
g <- gtable_add_grob(g,
                     grobs = rectGrob(gp = gpar(fill = NA, lwd = 2)),
                     t = 1, l = 1, r = ncol(g))

save_plot("table is cut off.tiff", g, dpi = 300)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming that `save_plot` comes from the cowplot package (there is more than one package with a function called `save_plot`), you can specify the height and aspect ratio like this:

```
save_plot("table isnt cut off.tiff", g, dpi = 300, base_height = 5.5, base_asp = 0.4)
```

[image]